# Using the map operator to retrieve a value from a list based on matching condition

Tags: angular

I am trying to implement the map operator on list collection of values in angular 7. I basically need to fetch the spf value for vehicleType id.
This list is bound to a dropdown control. So every time the user selects a value in the dropdown , spf for that value 
needs to be retreived and assigned to a field declared on the component.

VehicleTypes is list collection that contails values is id and spf in each element of its collection

How do I go about doing that ?

Here is my code

```
 IsVehicleDependent: boolean;

public vehicleTypeChanged(value: number): void {

        this.FundDetails.VehicleTypes.pipe(map(x=> x.VehicleTypeId === value));

        // Need to assign value to the result below
        this.IsVehicleDependent = 
    }
```

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: Is your `VehicleTypes` an array?

Comment: yes it is an array

Comment: Or do I just use the filter operator ?

Comment: Please find my updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

**UPDATED ANSWER:**

As per the object structure, it seems you want to find the object based on the field **ID** (which is 108 as shown in your example object). So, your code should be like

```
 this.IsVehicleDependent = this.FundDetails.VehicleTypes.find(x=> x.ID === value).SPF;
```

Comment: I have updated the post on how the array looks like

Comment: This is what i tried  this.IsVehicleDependent = this.FundDetails.VehicleTypes.find(x=> x.VehicleTypeId === value.ID).SPF;